# Hierarchical structure to view posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post type called promo that I am querying on the front end. I have created several user roles(System Admin, Company Admin, Account Coordinator ) and  I want to only allow access to the posts using a structure like the image below. Basically and Admin can view all posts, Company Admins can  view all account coordinators for that companies posts and Account Coordinators can only view their own posts and by posts I mean a custom post type "promo".

Currently I am restricting access to the author with something like

```
$args = array(
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
);
$promo = new WP_Query($args);
```

I left most of the code out for brevity. Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this viewing structure?

[image]

Comment: Well you know who posted what. You're already keeping track of who has what title. Can you just compare the person trying to view the post's title (or access level) against the poster's title (probably using a join clause to get the title of the poster)